# How can I connect a signal to QWidget::update slot?

Tags: qt

I am using Qt5 with new signal/slot syntax.
I don't know why the following code doesn't work:

```
QWidget *widget = new QWidget();
connect(pipeline, &Pipeline::NewFrame, widget, &QWidget::update);
```

I get the error:
`no matching member function for call to 'connect'` why?

Pipeline class inherits from QObject and NewFrame signal has the same signature as QWidget::update

```
class Pipeline
  : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_DISABLE_COPY(Pipeline)
public:
    Pipeline(QObject *parent);

signals:
    void NewFrame();
};
```

I am using QtCreator on Arch Linux with g++.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: The pipeline should be signaling an image, and the widget should have a `SetImage` method:

```
class Pipeline : public QObject {
  Q_OBJECT // important
public:
  Q_SIGNAL void NewFrame(const QImage &);
  ...
};

class Viewer : public QWidget {
  Q_OBJECT // important
  QImage m_image;
public:
  Q_SLOT void SetImage(const QImage &image) {
    m_image = image;
    update();
  }
  ...
};
```

This is how you'd be using it - note that `Viewer` knows nothing about `Pipeline`, because it shouldn't: it just shows new frames, wherever they come from.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  Pipeline pipeline;
  Viewer viewer;
  QObject::connect(&pipeline, &Pipeline::NewFrame, &viewer, &Viewer::SetImage);
  return app.exec();
}
```

Connecting anything to `QWidget::update` directly, especially from external sources, is usually a sign of bad design.

To satisfy your curiosity, you can use a lambda or [`qOverload`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtglobal.html#qOverload) to specify what you're connecting to, to fix the very error you're seeing - caused by ambiguity of the the type of the method pointer. Any of the following will work:

```
connect(…, widget, qOverload<>(&QWidget::update));
```

or

```
auto constexpr update = qOverload<>(&QWidget::update));
connect(…, widget, update);
```

or

```
connect(…, widget, [widget]{ widget->update(); });
```

Comment: It was bad design not only due to refactoring, but also because `YourWidget::paintEvent` won't have access to the image it should be using, and having it directly use, say `Pipeline::getImage() const` method is not only tight coupling, but can't be used across threads, or if `getImage` is expensive (nothing expensive other than painting itself should be done in `paintEvent`), etc.